# DDMS doesn't show process list on device

Tags: android, ddms

i am new in android app testing. i need to find the heap size and heap uses for a app. so i am doing this by using DDMS but there is a problem that, its not showing the running process of device.

Device .Nexus 6.0.1. Can you tell me please What am I missing here??

any help would be appreciated.

[See circle in the screenshot where the device is appear but its process not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIweH.png)

Comment: did you on developer option?if it is on then restart adb or eclipse/studio.

Comment: post the snapshot of your problem

Comment: Hi vasant , yes developer option is enable and also debugging mode is on.

Comment: try another data cable

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the problem.

If you only want to show the information of your app, adding *android:debuggable="true"* in the corresponding Manifest.xml.

Otherwise, rooting the device and flashing a customized boot.img with "ro.debuggable" set to 1.

Why? Check out:
[ro.debuggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143960/androidstudio-what-does-debuggable-do)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibilities:

1. Try to change another usb cable.

   - There are many cables only for charge, not for data connection. buy a cable with data connection maybe solve your problem.
2. Enable developer option

   - Go to the settings menu, and scroll down to "About phone." Tap it.
   - Scroll down to the bottom again, where you see "Build number." Tap it seven (7) times.
   - After the third tap, you'll see a playful dialog that says you're four taps away from being a developer. 
     Keep on tapping, you've got the developer settings back.
   - You dive into that menu to do things like enable USB debugging
3. Restart adb

   - adb kill-server
   - adb start-server

Comment: Hi Thermos , I have done all above things which you have mentioned but still process not appearing.

Comment: 1. download genymotion to DDMS works or not on simulator

2. you can try to use another android phone to see it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find step by step process for find the heap size.

[Heap Viewer Walkthrough](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/heap-viewer/index.html)

Hope this will help you..